# replace string of symbol+ rational number python

Tags: python, sentence

I have a large corpus which contains sentences such as

```
text = ["$3.4 million but not section 4.1"]
```

that I want to clean as

```
text = ["$3,4 million but not section 4.1"]
```

using a simple line such as

`text.replace("$\d.\d","$\d,\d")` or with `re.sub`.
but I don't know how to map the string *"$"+digit+"."* to *"$"+digit+","*

Any idea?
thanks

Comment: You can't use regular expressions with the string `.replace()` method. It will only search for literal substrings.

Comment: https://regex101.com/ will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def rep(m):
    return m.group(1) + "," + m.group(2)
re.sub("([$][0-9]+).([0-9]+)",rep,text)
```

Comment: The only trouble with this is that your dot is matching any character. I made the same mistake for a moment. If you feed it `"$3.4 and $999 million but not section 4.1"`, it yields `$3,4 and $9,9 million but not section 4.1`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend compiling your pattern if you have several lines to match. Assuming they all follow a pattern close to this, you can do something like:

```py
import re

p = re.compile(r"(\$\d+)\.(\d+)")

lines_before = [
    "$3.4 million but not section 4.1",
    "$75.6 foo 43.54",
]

lines_after = [p.sub(r"\1,\2", l) for l in lines_before]

print(lines_after)
```

Output:

```
['$3,4 million but not section 4.1', '$75,6 foo 43.54']
```

### Explanation

First, compile a regular expression that matches a literal "$" in any position, followed by one or more digits, followed by a literal ".", followed by one or more digits. This captures the parts preceding and following the ".".

Then, for each line, replace matches with capture group 1, followed by ",", then add the second capture group last.